# Formula to calculate next date excluding list of dates

Tags: excel, date, recursion, excel-formula, iteration

Can someone please help with formula to calculate the next available date excluding list of specific dates (blocked dates for some event). 
In the image attached, when a Plan date in column A is entered, it should calculate the invoice date based on 
1. Earliest invoice date is event date closest to (Plan date + 5 days). 
2. If the invoice date calculated is one of the blocked dates, the invoice date should be set to next working date

Step 1 above is calculated as shown in formula,

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$8-($A2+5)>=0,$B$2:$B$8))
```

For Step 2 any help is appreciated. When tried Vlookup on calculated invoice date to match the value in blocked dates - once it calculates next day. But when calculated next day is also blocked day, it fails. For example, in first data row, invoice date based in step 1 is 20-Jan-16 which is blocked date.

In step 2, if VLOOKUP is used to match 20-Jan-16 and increment by 1 day, it gives 21-Jan-16 which is again a blocked date. Any suggestions for recursion/iterative calculation to be done?

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ekq.png)

[image: OP's sample data]

The blocked dates are fairly large list for a year and in random order.

Comment: Is there any chance that Sat, Sun or both should be excluded?

Comment: I've added the [tag:excel] and [tag:excel-formula] in order that your question receives more focused attention.

Answer (score 2):

The [WORKDAY.INTL function¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D) should esspecially effective for this. Not only can you specify a range of *holidays* to be used as *blocked dates*, but you can specify a special **weekend string** that identifies the days to be regarded as weekends. Since you do not want to exclude any other days-of-the-week, this will be simply `"0000000"`.

In E2 as,

```
=IFERROR(WORKDAY.INTL(AGGREGATE(15, 6, (B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )))/(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B ))-(A2+5)>=0), 1)-1, 1, "0000000", C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))), "")
```

Since we are dealing with second generation functions, I changed your `MIN(IF(...` array formula to an [AGGREGATE² function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) which does not have to be array entered and used a wrapping [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to avoid displaying a `#DIV/0!` error in E8.

Fill down as necessary.

[image: workday_intl_aggregate]

---

¹ <sub>The [WORKDAY.INTL function¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: This is working awesome. Thank you very much. Invoice date is derived value based on some other validations. Trying to combine all formulas.